# Python calling a method from a different file defined in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, nose

I am trying to write a unit test. My unit test file is test_file . My main code is in a file(main_file.py) which has a class defined and several methods.
All my files are in same dir, so my tree structure looks like :

```html
├── main_file.py
├── __init__.py
├── test_file.py
```

In my main_file i have a class name my_class and has method send_request.

In my test file i am trying to import the method to use:
`from main_file import send_request`

and when i run my unit test (python test_file.py) or even using nosetests it keeps throwing error:
ImportError: No module named main_file

my **init**.py is just empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you are importing a file, you need to import the CLASS and not just the method if it is inside of a class. So you would need to do:

```
from main_file import my_class
```

instead of importing the function within the class. Then when you call the class you can do something such as

```
my_class.send_request()
```

when you call the function in your new .py

As you know you could import all of the classes and modules from main_file by doing:

```
import main_file
from main_file import *
```

Which will get you all of the classes/functions as well, although that may not be what you're looking for.

Besides that I would make sure they're all in the same directory again, and if it still fails, I usually just save everything to my "downloads" folder. When all else fails, and then it works.

Comment: I tried to do this but now i get error ImportError: No module named main_file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import class to use the method

```
from main_file import my_class
from my_class import FUNCTION_NAME or from my_class import *
```

Comment: same issue i cant even do `from main_file import my_class`
i get ImportError: No module named `main_file`